# Push Notifications from different app :/

Tags: push-notification, push

My application is receiving push notifications of the other application.
I think that's because of my fault. I accidentally built one app with other's bundleID.
So, my question is how to remove my new app from Push Notification list of the other one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most possible is that you have signed both your applications with same distribution profile.
When the app registers for push notifications it sends that profile info with device token.